# Verification of proof of an inequality without using induction

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, solution-verification

Here is the question:

If $a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_n$ are all positive, and $s_n=a_1+a_2+\ldots+a_n$, then
$$(1+a_1)(1+a_2)\ldots(1+a_n)\le1+s_n+\frac{s_n^2}{2!}+\ldots+\frac{s_n^n}{n!}.$$

Proof:
Any term in the expression in the left hand side of the proof will be of form:
$$a_{i_1}a_{i_2}a_{i_3}.......a_{i_k}$$
where $i_1,i_2,i_3,i_4,......,i_k$ are different integers within $1$ and $n$ and $k$ denotes the length of the term which can be within $1$ and $n$ and the coefficient of each term will be $1$.
Here,in the right hand side of the inequality, for any given positive integer $k$ within $1$ and $n$ we see that,$$s_n^k=(a_1+a_2+.....+a_n)^k$$ and thus, the expression contains every term of length $k$ as in the left hand side of inequality. The coefficient of $a_{i_1}a_{i_2}a_{i_3}.......a_{i_k}$  is $k!$ in $s_n^k=(a_1+a_2+.....+a_n)^k$. So, Let us denote the sum of all such terms $a_{i_1}a_{i_2}a_{i_3}.......a_{i_k}$ by $X_k$ so as to obtain :
$$k!X_k\leq s_n^k\Rightarrow X_k\leq \frac{s_n^k }{k!}$$. Thus, we get,by summing up all such inqualitities,
$$(1+a_1)(1+a_2)......(1+a_n)\leq 1+s_n+\frac{s_n^2}{2!}+....+\frac{s_n^n}{n!}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution is right but has some ambiguities which make it uneasy to follow.
For example, the choice of $(i_1,\dots,i_k)$ in the initial expression is how? $(i_1,\dots,i_k)$ is chosen as an ordered $k$-tuples or a subset of $k$ elements of $\{1,2,..,n\}$?
I understand what you want but to have a more rigorous proof, you have to be clear on points like that.
Anyways, it's a creative and good solution.

Comment: Should I write the choice of $(i_1,i_2,......,i_k)$ as a subset of $k$ elements of $\{1,2,.....,n\}$?

Comment: yeah, or perhaps, $i_1<\dots<i_k$ is enough.